# Is it possible to alias a template function member of a template class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

There is a way to alias a function template member of a template class?

for instance let's take

```
template<typename T, int ndim>
class Point
{
  // ... stuff

  template<int index>
  T get() const;   
}
```

instead of using `p.get<0>()` does exists a way to declare an alias like

```
using getX() =  template<typaname T, ndim> Point<T,ndim>::get<0>()
p.getX() // call p.get<0>()
```

?

*I'm aware of the fact I could write an `enable_if getX` which wraps `get<0>()` enabled if `ndims` match it. I'd like to know if does exists a way **through aliasing**.*

Comment: You could easily get it to work with `getX(p)` if you re okay with changing the syntax.

Comment: How would you do this in a non-template case? `using g() = X::f();` (or similar) does not work...

Comment: @NathanOliver please explain

Comment: @MaxLanghof for a non-template just do not exists a real use case for me, just rename the function

Comment: `auto getX = [](const auto& p) { return p.get<0>(); };` will give you a `getX` that does what you want.  You just call it as `getX(object_name);`

Comment: @NathanOliver I undertand, but it's more close to what I would to reach through a wrapper function, since I'd like ti use a p.getX(). But still, thanks for that option

Comment: In this case, a wrapper function would likely be inlined, provided it just calls the wrapped function and returns the results.

Answer (score 0):

No alias for function, but you can create code "similar":

- lambda or function helper:

  ```
  auto getX = [](const auto& p) { return p.get<0>(); };
  getX(p);
  ```
- pointer on member function:

  ```
  auto getX = &Point<float, 3>::get<0>;
  (p.*getX)();
  ```

Comment: Note: this will only work in C++14, not C++11. The OP has tagged only C++11.

Comment: @badola: Indeed, fixed argument for lambda in c++11 (instead of generic lambda),  template function helper can still be done to be generic in C++11.